# Error in logic probably

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop

I'm teaching myself bash

How can I make this work?

There are three check points... No blank lines, No special characters and 
No numbers less than 1 and greater than the biggest number

However, on the third checkpoint, if you try to enter a special character, the whole thing comes tumbling down like a house of card.

How can I make sure the user doesn't enter a blank line, no special characters and no number less than 1 and greater than a predetermined biggest number?

read -p "Please enter the line number: " line_number

```
# First checkpoint
# No blank lines accepted as input
while [[ -z "$line_number" ]] ;
do
echo
echo "Line number can not be blank."
echo
read -p "Please enter a valid line number? " line_number
echo
done

# Second checkpoint
# No special characters allowed as input
# Escaping the backtick or accent grave requires three back slashes before the backtick
while [[ $line_number == *['!'@#\$%^\&*()_+?~-\"\\\`]* ]] ; 
do
echo
echo "No special characters allowed"
echo
read -p "Please enter a valid line number? " line_number
echo
done

# Third checkpoint
# No number less than 1 and greater than the $total_line_number
while [[ $line_number -lt 1 || $line_number -gt $total_line_number ]] ; 
do
echo
echo -e "Line number can not be lesser than 1$ and bigger than              $total_line_number."
echo 
read -p "Please enter a number between the 1 and  $total_line_number scope? " line_number
echo
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's supposed to be a line number, there's no need to distinguish between "regular" characters like `a` and "special" characters like punctuation. The only thing you want to accept are digits:

```
line_number=
until [[ $line_number = +([[:digit:]]) &&
         $line_number -ge 1 &&
         $line_number -le $total_line_number  ]]; do
    read -p "Please enter a valid number between 1 and $total_line_number: " line_number
done
```

Comment: I wish to learn bash script and become proficient. I try to read the guides, however, I don't think I would have figured this out without your help. And you were not even condescending.  Kudos!  Thanks a lot for your time and expertise!

Comment: I guess this requires `shopt -s extglob` too, right?

Comment: Recent versions (i.e., 4.1+) of `bash` turn `extglob` on temporarily while evaluating `[[...]]` commands.